# How clear all checkboxs and radiobuttons with a pushbutton in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5

[image]

I want when pushing the `clear all choices` button, all checkboxes and radio buttons are be unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->checkBox->setChecked(false);
    ui->radioButton->setChecked(false);
    // Add all other check boxes and radio buttons you have...
}
```